# django ImportError: No module named plugins

Tags: django, plugins, content-management-system

i need some help. 
I searched in internet but i didn't find any response. I'n new in python nad django :) that causes that i'm here. 
Maybe i start at the beginning, i have some project django on heroku hosting, and i have repository on git. I check and i don't have ftp connection to heroku :/ and i have only repository on git. In this repository is requirement.txt file but there no information about version of modules.
I want to prepare enviroment on my ubuntu, i downloaded my existing django project and i started server by command

```
python manage.py server
```

I was informed by python that i need to install some of module, and library of python etc. Everything went ok until apperad info

> ImportError: No module named plugins

There is no  name of plugins this showed just plugins. I installed some module like django-plugins ( i think that module have a folder i dist-package like djangoplugins ). It did not help :/, than i created new folder in dist-package ( in python library folder )   "plugins" and i copied content form djangoplugins . This did not help :/. again showed me "ImportError: No module named plugins". i don't have any idea , whats i need to install, i installed every plugins i found in internet and it didn't help. 
Maybe you had this problem ? i know that django can be 1.6 version.]

=====================================
**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I have wrong version of django and django-cms.

Comment: `runserver` not `server`

Comment: Can you post your settings.py, models.py and views.py?

Comment: Seluck i don't have one file like setting.py i have setting folder with common.py and dev.py and prod.py. Do i show all files ?

Comment: If you run `python manage.py runserver --traceback` you may get more info about your error.

Comment: Thanks for help, i find file with version of modules. Thanks !!